# Python - How to Concatenate Strings in a Successive Way?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

could you tell me whether there is a more elegant solution to my code what I need?

My little program takes text input from up to seven entry fields (exact number can be
specified by the user). The input strings are then concatenated with interspersed fixed
text elements. A single output in the form of a string is generated.

The program works perfectly fine. Yet, my programming strikes me as very inelegant and non-pythonic. Could you help me to improve, to foster my learning?

Two points:

**1)** I like to sum up the string length of all seven text inputs. I plainly added them,
which is not elegant. How could I do it a better way?

```
string_length = len(str(E1.get())) + len(str(E2.get())) + len(str(E3.get())) +   len(str(E4.get())) + len(str(E5.get())) + len(str(E6.get())) + len(str(E7.get()))
```

**2)**
Depending on the number of entry field which can be specified by the user using a Tkinter Scale **S**, Entry fields(**En**) are enabled or disabled for taking input.

The Strings **str(En.get())** derived from these Entry field are then concatenated with
the fixed string elements **partM** in between to give rise to the string **m**. (The whole string is flanked with partL and partR on each side also.) I have done this by query the variable of
the scale **S** (number of entry fields) via the get() method. 
The program then decides how to proceed via if / elif?

The higher the scale is set the more text elements are added. Yet this is highly similar task which strikes me as there might be a more straight forward solution.

This creates long lines of code and is not very amenable for scaling up the program for taking more Entry fields. How could I do it better?

***code excerpt:***

```
if S.get() == 1:
    if string_length == 22*S.get():        
        m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partR
        do_something()
    else:
        warning()

elif S.get() == 2:
    if string_length == 22*S.get():            
        m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partM + str(E2.get()) + partR
        do_something()
    else:
        warning()

elif S.get() == 3:
    if string_length == 22*S.get():
        m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partM + str(E2.get()) + partM + str(E3.get()) + partR
        do_something()
    else:
        warning()
```

I am very new to Python. I am also new to programming. Yet I am proud I write a little code that works fine and does something useful for me and others.
I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I've never before seen a question more beautifully asked by a first timer.

Comment: Really? Thanks for your kind words, Ashish Nitin Patil!

Answer (score 6):

If your fields are E1 through E7 and each has a `get` method this should give you the total length of them:

```
fields = [E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7]
total_length = sum(len(str(f.get())) for f in fields)
```

If you just want the values collected, this suffices:

```
fields = [E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7]
values = [f.get() for f in fields]
```

Comment: It may also be advisable to just make a list of fields from the start instead of using `E1`, `E2`, `E3`, etc. variables.

Comment: What is a facile way to load the input of my fields into a list?

Answer (score 1):

i'll try answer the second part of the question since @g.d.d.c already has a very good answer to the first part.

To avoid code repeat you should look at common sections among your existing code.

```
if string_length == 22*S.get():
    ...
else:
    warning()
```

appears in all three cases. Therefore you can extract it to be:

```
if string_length != 22*S.get():
    warning()
else:     
    if S.get() == 1:
        ...
    elif S.get() == 2:
        ...
    elif S.get() == 3:
        ...
    do_something()
```

if you foresee to support more cases, you can expand with a function map

```
functions = {1 : one,
                2 : two,
                3 : three
}

def one():
    m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partR

def two():
    m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partM + str(E2.get()) + partR

def three():
    m = partL + str(E1.get()) + partM + str(E2.get()) + partM + str(E3.get())
```

and you call with:

```
functions[S.get()]()
```

Comment: I'd recommend reversing the `if` test, so the short `warning()` clause comes before the big long thing that'll make you forget what you even wanted to warn about.

Comment: Great I do that!Thank you so much zaftcoAgeiha!

Answer (score 1):

The `if string_length == 22*S.get()` check happens regardless of the value of `S.get()`, and if it fails, you always raise a warning. To simplify your code and reduce code duplication, you can move that check outside of the logic that switches based on the value of `S.get()`:

```
if string_length != 22*S.get():
    warning()
else:
    if S.get() == 1:
        ...
    elif S.get() == 2:
        ...
    ...
```

If you make a list of fields instead of using 7 numbered variables, it's easy to use slicing and indexing to select the fields you want in a scalable way without needing separate clauses for every number. Also, the `join` method of strings allows you to join together a number of strings with a delimiter you specify:

```
if string_length != 22*S.get():
    warning()
else:
    middle = partM.join(str(field.get()) for field in fields[:S.get()])
    m = partL + middle + partR
    do_something()
```

Let's break down `partM.join(str(field.get()) for field in fields[:S.get()])`:

`fields` should be the list of fields you made instead of using 7 variables.

`fields[:S.get()]` is slicing notation. It makes a list of the first `S.get()` elements of `fields`. (If `fields` doesn't have enough elements, the slice returns a copy of the whole list.)

`str(field.get()) for field in fields[:S.get()]` is a generator expression. It creates an iterator that loops over `fields[:S.get()]` and calls the `get()` method of every field in the list. This results in an iterator over the strings from the first `S.get()` fields. (Generator expressions must always appear in parentheses. If a generator expression is the only argument to a function, the function call parentheses fill this role. Otherwise, you must stick parentheses around it.)

`partM.join(str(field.get()) for field in fields[:S.get()])` takes all the strings from that iterator and sticks them together, separated by `partM` between each pair of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well a way to join strings in to use the .join(insert something here) method. This is basically the string equivalent of the function .append(Insert something here).